# Copying data from the child window of exe file in Windows

Tags: windows, c#

I have an app like this one. I cannot CTRL+C or right click to copy data from DataTable. Does anyone know how to copy all the data from the child window?
[image]

Comment: If you want to be able to copy data out of a DataTable you have to provide that functionality to your application yourself.  This is the case for all applications, if you want operating system clipboard functionality, it has to be programmed by the author of the software.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [SysInternals'](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/) Process Explorer x64 – `procexp64.exe`.  Open the properties dialogue for your .exe and navigate to the Strings tab.  However, you will need to parse through the data yourself and may need to get creative in extracting the data you want (e.g., use [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/) or any other word processor that includes a regex search function).

I've never tried before, but ***if*** you can select the file as a data source, you can try connecting to it from Excel and see if it can pull the table for you; advantage to that would be minimal efforts to redo table structuring/formatting.

In some cases – and this is *completely* subjective to the individual programs and their developers – the file may be directly decompressed by renaming the file to .zip and extracting.

One last option I can think of off the top of my head would be screenshots and using an OCR utility to reconstruct all the field strings.

Comment: What file can be rename to zip and extract?

Comment: BTW I tried Process Explorer but it doesn't give me proper data to parse, almost unparsable

Comment: @MiskoMali Off the top of my head, .docx files, .apk files, *some* installers, etc.  Certain Android files (like .bk AFAIR) can also be directly decompressed that way after altering two bits via a hex editor, can't remember the procedure exactly though.